# Присвоение элементу структуры1 тип структуры2

Tags: c++

как быть если в структуре item есть член someItem и как ему присвоить значение, если он тип 1 структуры list? имею 2 структ

```
    struct list
    {
        DWORD Count;
        char treeItem[9];
    };
struct item
{
    list someItem[9];
    int num;
};

    item itemOne;
    itemOne.num= 1;
// Как присвоить simeItem тип list???
        itemOne.someItem=;

//////////////////////////////////////////
         // Работает, все отлично

        list Neewlist;
        Neewlist.Count = 5;
strcpy(Neewlist.treeItem ,"12345678");
```

Comment: Никак, вам же в предыдущем вопросе написали, что массивы в С++ нельзя присваивать. Используйте `::std::array` или функцию типа `::std::memcpy`. Или инициализируйте сразу при создании.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Потрудитесь выражаться яснее. Что и куда вы собрались присваивать? У вас там массив. Чем вы собрались заполнять массив?

Comment: Всему массиву разом присвоить что-то нельзя, но отдельному элементу можно. Так что примерно так: `itemOne.someItem[i] = {...};`.